# Dragonborn DLC is in a different language from the rest of the game

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

I have the Dragonborn DLC installed, but the characters voices all seem to be in Polish. Yet, the rest of my game is in English and I don't know why. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: What platform are you playing on?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you installed the DLC in Polish, if you didn't try and reloading a save from before you accessed the DLCs' content.